# What's a good way to get Demonite ore in terraria?

Tags: terraria

I want to get as much Demonite ore as possible to make Shadow armor and to sell the leftover ore, but there is no way I could get enough from mining.What should I do?

Comment: Only way to get it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way to obtain large amounts of Demonite Ore is to defeat [Eater of Worlds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds). Over and over. It can be summoned using [Worm Food](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Worm_Food).

Comment: Any of the starter bosses drop Demonite Ore. While the Eater of Worlds drops the most, the Eye of Cthulhu also drops a good amount and may be easier to beat than the Eater of World, depending on player skill.

Comment: Worth noting that you want a Corrupt world rather that a Crimson world to make it easier

Comment: To craft Shadow armor though you will need shadow scales which _only_ drop from the Eater of Worlds and cannot be found or mined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get demonite ore is to either farm the EOW (eater of worlds) or EOC (eye of Cthulhu). If you want crimtane ore which is basically the same. Farm the BOC (brain of Cthulhu).

Answer (score -2):

Have 1 world with the stuff you need to kill the eye of Cthulhu lots of times, then go make as many worlds as you need. It will take time to wait but it will spawn then kill it.

Comment: You know you can repeat all the bosses, right?

Answer (score -3):

Definitely the best way is defeating the eater of worlds. He drops a ton of shadow scales and demonite ore. He even drops some when you've done some but not all damage to him. You can also rarely get armor similar to demonite armor from corruption enemies. If you didn't know how to spawn him, here's a link to the boss:

https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds